# How to Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy with Network RP (RP service principal name)?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

ok, here's the blog post on how to use certificate with Key Vault - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/24/deploying-azure-web-app-certificate-through-key-vault/. And it says:

> > ‘abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd’ is the RP service principal name and it remains same for all Azure subscriptions.

Where the hell this guid come from????

I need the same but for Network provider.
Please explain how to get it.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to use a certificate from KeyVault in deploying Point-to-Site VPN, and here it's  not Web App RP, it's Network RP. Or, I'm definitely missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the guid of your web application in Azure Active Directory. You need to add the application to AD so it can be authorised to use key vault. Follow [this msft guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/) to add it to AD and get the guid, then you can use the Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy cmdlet.

Comment: So, I have an ARM template that creates an AppService (web app) and I need certificate in the same template because this AppService must be part of VNet. All this means I have to have some parts in the template and others in Powershell. Great!

But thank you for the answers. At least, that's something for a start.